# React grid elements, show details about specified element after clicking it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i have created gird of elements (something like gallery) `AllElements` Component where i am mapping `SingleElement` Component

```
renderAllElements = () => (
            this.state.myData.map(se => (
                <SingleElement key={se.id} name={se.name} tagline={se.tagline} image_url={se.image_url}/>
        )
    )
)
```

And my SingleElement renders this, as below

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="singleElement">
            <img src={this.props.image_url} alt={this.props.name} />
            <h4>{this.props.name}</h4>
            <h5>{this.props.tagline}</h5>
        </div>
    )
}
```

To the point, what I want achieve? ---> After clicking on one of the elements (specyfied `SingleElement`) the details is shown in front of the screen (hovering over whole grid). Let's name this Component `SingleElementDetails`. What is the best way to achieve it? Should `SingleElementDetails` Component be sibling of `SingleElement` Component or it's child ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `AllElements` state and an method to handle when/what to show.
Something like this:

```
class AllElements extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myData: {},
      viewingElement: null,
    };
    this.see = this.see.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  see(id) {
    this.setState({
      viewingElement: id,
    });
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({
      viewingElement: null,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { myData, viewingElement } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {myData.map(se => (
          <SingleElement
            key={se.id}
            name={se.name}
            tagline={se.tagline}
            image_url={se.image_url}
            see={this.see}
            close={this.close}
          />
        ))}
        {viewingElement && (
          <SingleElementDetails element={myData[this.state]} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then you need to fire `this.props.see` on the onClick event from `SingleElement` and use CSS to visually position `SingleElementDetails` over the rest of the contest.